# MVC4 Web API ignoring parameters

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Trying to set up a new site using MVC RC4 web API in Visual Studio 2010, and it just seems to not work: parameter values are never passed to the method.

As far as I can tell I have done everything exactly as described here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Route configuration:

```
  routes.Clear();
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { 
           id = RouteParameter.Optional 
      }
  );
```

Below is the regular MVC route, I've also tried just removing this entirely to see if there
was some conflict but it made no difference.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { 
          controller = "Home", 
          action = "Index", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional 
      }
  );
```

Test controller:

```
  public class TestController : ApiController
  {
        [HttpGet]
        public int Double(int value)
        {
            return value * 2;
        }
  }
```

URL:  `http://localhost:1505/api/test/double/4`

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'value' of 
non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Int32 Double(Int32)' in
'MyAppName.Controllers.TestController'. An optional parameter must be a
reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Argh. This is about as simple as it gets isn't it? But nothing seems to result in the parameter being mapped. For the heck of it I also tried

```
http://localhost:1505/api/test/double?id=4
```

No difference. If I make the parameter accept null values, e.g.

```
public int Double(int? value)
```

it runs, but `value` is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your route you have `{id}` but in your action you have `value` and MVC matches the "things" (route values, query string values etc.) by name.

So the names should align:

So change your routing to :

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{value}",
      defaults: new { 
           value= RouteParameter.Optional 
      }
  );
```

And it will work with the URL: `http://localhost:1505/api/test/double/4`

Note: if you leave the `value` `RouteParameter.Optional` you need to change type in your action's signature to `int?`.

Or you can change your action method signature:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public int Double(int id)
    {
        return id * 2;
    }
```

Or you can leave it as it is just use this URL:

`http://localhost:1505/api/test/double?value=4`

Comment: So basically, the parameter name in the method has to match the name used in the template? Does this mean that that I have to create a route for every possible method even if it matches an existing pattern (or use ID as my parameter name no matter what)? Ugh..

Comment: @jamietre it's a little bit oversimplification but yes. In MVC and Web.API a component called ModelBinder is responsible for matching the incoming data (route parameters, query string, from collection) with the parameter objects. And it matches them by name. You can search for ModelBinder and ValueProviders if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. Seems unusual that it matches by the actual parameter name and not just the signature, kind of defeats the purpose of a template!

Answer (score 0):

This case happen for me when i have not defining the attribute **[RoutePrefix("")]** and **[Route("")]** for my controller and action method in web api.Its works for me perfectly after adding these.